# Search issue with OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We have google maps implemented with markerclusterer and OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier. Clustering and Spiderfy working fine. But we have implemented search where user search for a specific location based on name and below function will be called. Search is working fine except for the locations with same coordinates. We have implemented OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier and working fine but for spiderified locations zoom in not working fine and its pointing to map center.

```
function showMarkerInfo(index)
{

    hidePopup('popup');

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(filterMarker[index].get('LATITUDE'),filterMarker[index].get('LONGITUDE')));

    idleMapZoomListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(filterMarker[index], "click");
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(MAP_INIT_LAT,MAP_INIT_LNG));

        google.maps.event.removeListener(idleMapZoomListener);
    });


    if (map.getZoom() == 16 ) {
        map.setZoom(17);
    } else {
        map.setZoom(16);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

We used oms.trigger("click",filterMarker[index]); instead of  google.maps.event.trigger(filterMarker[index], "click"); and its working fine.